# making comment a entire method at one time

Tags: java, eclipse

sometimes it happens that we need to make comment a entire method in Java and reactive, more than once in same code in same time to test something. so is there any way in eclipse by which a method can be commented from its start or end, without going to the end and start for making comment?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard let consider, ur code has a method, want to comment it, then u can do end of line of each line of the method or can make it /**/, but to do "/**/" ,we have to go at least at the end and the start of the method.but i want to do it form only the start of the method or from end.i hope u got it, if not then i will try to edit my Q by uploading a fragment of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position on the method name and use Alt+Shift+Up twice to select the entire method. Then use Ctrl+/ to comment the selected text.

Comment: ur answer is very helpful but it is for only making comment, how to make uncomment like this way?

Comment: I haven't found a similar method to select a whole block of commented code. It's a bit frustrating :(

Answer (score 1):

First Drag Mouse and Select the `Method` then

1. `Press Left(cntrl+shift+/)` to **comment**
2. `Press Left(cntrl+shift+\)` to **uncomment**